# Gridview Pagination error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination in my gridview control. Here is the code for databind and pageindexchanged

```
Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim dataTable as DataTable = CType(Session.Item(APPLICATION_DATA), DataTable)
    Grid.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView
    Grid.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnChangePageSize(ByVal send As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles Grid.PageIndexChanging
    Grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    _BindGrid()
End Sub
```

But I get error after Grid.DataBind() as

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs'"
```

Why this error? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

That won't anyways make any difference as the name of the event handler (PageIndexChanging in this case) can be anything since it is defined in the aspx file too. However my issue is resolved since i was firing a OnPageIndexChanging from aspx and handling that in OnPageIndexChanged. Correct that and it worked.